# Use of undeclared Identifier FirstViewController when pushing a view controller from other views

Tags: ios, view, viewcontroller

I want to push a `ViewController` called `FirstViewController` from other views, I did :

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
FirstViewController *First = [[FirstViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:First animated:YES];
```

but I always get this error : Use of undeclared Identifier FirstViewController. I used the same code for other views in the same application and everything was fine, I don't know why it doesn't work for the `FirstViewController` .

How Can I fix this problem?

Comment: Just a tip, it's convention to start your variable names with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of FirstViewController file doestn't exist in compile source.
Solution is
Go to build phase->compile source->add your file if it is missing.

Comment: I checked the compile source and it contains the FirstViewController file